# How to pass multiple dynamic ! -path arguments to find

Tags: find, search

I have a file which contains a list of directories/files that I want to ignore when searching using find. It looks like this:

```
.git
.vim
config
.vimrc
.bashrc
```

This list is not exhaustive and can have any number of items. How can I ignore these files/directories when using `find`.

I've been trying to do `find . -type f ! -path ...`, but haven't been able to pass dynamic list as argument.

Comment: @αғsнιη, maybe so but that one ([Exclude a list of directories from unix find command](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/358122)) is closed as unclear, so we can't close this one as a duplicate of that one as then it would become unanswerable.

Comment: Do you want to ignore any file/dir named like that, or just the ones at the top-level directory?

Comment: I want to ignore any file/dir on any subsequent level (not just on level 1).

Comment: the answer to the dupe isn't able to handle spaces in the filenames from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `find` implementations that support `-regex` with extended regular expressions (`-E -regex` in BSD, `-regextype posix-extended -regex` in GNU), you could do:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex "\./($(
  sed 's@[][\\|^$.*+?{}()]@\\&@g' < list | paste -sd '|' -))" -prune -o \( \
    -type f -print \)
```

That excludes those file/dirs and any file/subdir within (`find` doesn't even descend into them thanks to `-prune`).

If if want to match any file/dir named like that at any level in the directory tree as opposed to only the ones in `.`, change the `\.` to `.*`.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a wrapper function for that:

```
find_exclude(){
    while read -r ext; do set "$@" \! -name "$ext"; done
    find . -type f "$@"
}

$ find -type f
./config
./.vim
./dir/.git
./list
$ cat list
.vim
.git
config
$ find_exclude <list
./list
```